# Will UTF-8 character encoding pose any security implication in web application?

Tags: security, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, utf-8

We have a Servlet/Jsp web application deployed under tomcat. It came to our attention that it does NOT support extended ASCII characters as of today, that is, to support user inputs that contain "extended ASCII" characters such as   é ü ç. We do not need to support internationalization.

My investigation and prototyping shows that, our server (servlet/jsp) side should explicitly set character encoding for request and response to "UTF-8". Then things would work. (This is a simplification. I know there are many layers. But this is the offender in our case. Our existing server side code is oblivious to character encoding).

So far so good. However the handling of character encoding has security implications for Web apps. As I read OWASP, most security issues or attack related to unicode seems to related to older UTF-8 Parsers. But should this still be an issue with modern browser ( https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Canonicalization,_locale_and_Unicode ) ? This is excerpt from OWASP.

> *Wherever input data is allowed, data can be entered using Unicode to disguise malicious code and permit a variety of attacks*

In short, if we want to change the character encoding in servlet from default("ISO-8859-1 " per servlet spec) to "UTF-8", are we going to cause any new security issues? Or any pointers on an concrete attack example, and how server side code can protect itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever issues there are, your code would probably already be vulnerable to them precisely because it is oblivious to unicode encoding, since the browser will already send  you unicode whether you want it or not (if the user pastes it into a form, like for example pasting text they copied from MS Word, which will have those curly quotes). The issue is basically if you are checking against certain characters for security reasons, but don't realize there are a ton of unicode characters that can get transformed to that character at a later step that you're missing at this one.  Like if for some reason you were checking for " but didn't take the curly quotes into account.

Comment: For the specific example you are citing, I am not clear on why unicode characters get transformed at a later step than the security check at application code level? Here are the order of events that I think:

Comment: (a)Before application code  calls "request.getParameter(xxx)", it has to know "character encoding". If not specified, then servlet spec defaults to ISO-8859-1. Container would have to decode the user input  parameter value (b) Then application code can do its security check as needed. So "unicode decoding or whatever decoding" performed at container level would happen before application level security check per my understanding?

Comment: Maybe I get what you meant: since browser can send characters in unicode no matter what, then if server side is oblivious to unicode, then container level decoding will not decode the user input properly, hence application level security check can miss some checks. Please advise.

Comment: If for instance you weren't using prepared statements on your db, and were using double quote rather than single as your string quotes. If you did like `sql="select * from table where x=\""+param+"\"";` the db server might transform the unicode curly quotes in the param to regular quotes. Maybe you even tried replacing all quotes in the param with something else. It would fail. That's one reason why prepared statements are the way to go.